# how to remove a specific line in bash/linux?

Tags: linux, text-processing

say I am given this file

```
username1
username2
username3
```

I want to delete a line that contains something I say. Like for example:

```
$ deletestuff abovefile username2
$ cat file
username1
username3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sed -i` to edit in place.  `/regexp/d` deletes lines matching `regexp`.

```
sed -i /username2/d file
```

To match whole lines (so that, for example, `username222` is not also removed) use `^` and `$` to anchor the search to start and end of the line.

```
sed -i '/^username2$/d' file
```